# PHP throw exception from caller

Tags: php, exception

Is it possible to throw an exception which seems to originate from the caller of a function instead of inside the called function.

```
function assert_foo(){
  throw new CustomException();
}

/* ... */

assert_foo(); // <-- I want the exception to seem to originate from here */
```

The `assert_foo` function would only be used for testing code where the test framework only shows the location where the exception originated from and not the full callstack. The only logic in `assert_foo` is to validate state.

I tried to override Exception::getTrace but `Cannot override final method Exception::getTrace()`.

Comment: It isn't possible, and if you need it in order to do something (what?) then you have taken the wrong path. Perhaps `if(!assert_foo()) throw new CustomException()`?

Comment: No, I sincerely doubt it. Having your assertions raise exceptions is pretty crazy behaviour; they're supposed to halt execution outright, not raise swallowable exceptions that might be caught and ignored. You want the built-in `assert`.

Comment: You may catch your exception where assert_foo is called and throw custom execption from there mimicing what you want to achieve.

Comment: It is for unittest code, the purpose isn't to halt execution but to detect errors during development. Maybe the `assert` is bad naming. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
function assert_foo()
{
   throw new CustomException();
}

/* ... */

assert_foo();
```

to:

```
function assert_foo()
{
   throw new CustomException();
}

/* ... */

try
{
    assert_foo(); //AAA
}
catch(CustomException $ce )
{
  // create new and throw from here 
  throw new CustomException();
}
```

now you have what you wanted ie. your exception will be seen as if it originated from **AAA** line

Comment: I guess it would work but a bit more tedious than I hoped for.

Comment: That's exactly what you wanted and asked for ;-). You may not need it as I do not know the context but that's it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was hoping for something magic to solve it without fixing the framework to show the full callstack.